# NET MAUI auth token in SecureStorage

Tags: blazor, access-token, bearer-token, facebook-access-token, maui

I have created a net MAUI Blazor app

I am able to login to facebook/google and return a auth token. What I'm trying to do is to save the token using SecureStorage in my app so that the user doesn't have to log in every time the user opens the app.

My issue is that tokens has an expiry date so I'm not sure how it will work. Even if I use a refresh token the token would have expired by the next time the user opens the app

My question is, what should I save in SecureStorage and how can I authenticate without the user having to re login every time

Comment: But that is what a "refresh token" is for: you use it to automatically obtain a current access token, thus logging the user in again. Test it, and report back with exact details of what you did, if you can't get it to work. [CAVEAT: I've never used these tokens; I'm just reading the docs.]

Comment: as Steve mentions, you store the refresh token each time and use that on the next request.  When the refresh token expires, then the user needs to login again